# Does changing regions cause me to lose my characters on the previous region?

Tags: diablo-iii

I switched for Euro server to US server last night, and I think this made me lose my character. If I was to change back to Euro server whould I get my character back? Or is there any way to get my character back?

Answer (score 4):

While you can switch from region to region, your characters remain on the region they were created on.  So if you change back to the European region, your previously created character(s) should be there.